# Alternate of href while using Angular component

Tags: angular

I have two components. **filter** and **filter-control**. I used **filter-control** in my **filter** component like this :

```
<filter-control (pressEnter)="apply()" [options]="filter" 
[(ngModel)]="filters[filter.key]" (ngModelChange)="modelChange(filterGroup)">
</filter-control>
```

somewhere at the bottom I implemented an anchor :

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="apply()" data-toggle="collapse" href="#m{{tabId}}">
      Search
    </a>
```

Bootstrap by default provides a **data-toggle="collapse"** functionality along with **href** attribute or **data-target** attribute which collapses a portion of webpage. I implemented this in my anchor tag as shown above. I want to implement this collapse functionality over my **filter-control** component as well. Any clues?

Comment: href has nothing to do with angular. It's a standard HTML attribute of links, which tells the link where it should navigate to when clicked. You can't just put href anywhere. Only on links.

Comment: I know this, but I still tried that's why I mentioned it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Input" would see to be what you're looking for. You need an Input on your filter controlled that you can use to set your url data.

But, this line is confusing:

"Now I want data-toggle and href in this anchor tag to (???) *associate* (???) with filter-control tag as well."

Properties and attributes on components and tags don't just implicitly associate by placing them in templates. If the property or attribute is not native to the element, you set up an Input. And "href" has nothing to do with any of your custom components unless you create an input to make it so.

Note however that I probably wouldn't create a property called "href" on a custom component. That's a native attribute of an "a" tag and could cause some confusion. I'd probably call it "nav-url" or something. But there is no *technical* reason it wouldn't work, as far as I know.

If you need more data on "inputs", just search for "Inputs in Angular Components".

So, in your template:

```
....
<a href={{myInputName}} etc...>
```

And component:

```
export class MyComponent (etc)...
@Input () myInputName;
```

You would now set that value this way:

```
<MyComponent [myInputName]="whateverValueIWant"></MyComponent>
```

You might be trying to do something like this...don't..

```
<MyComponent><a href={{someVal}}>blah</a></MyComponent>
```

If that's what you're trying to do...stop. The "a" tag belongs in the template of that component, and you would bind the value via an Input. There is actually a way to do it this way (or at least there used to be), but why bother, there's a very straightforward way to go about it already.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It makes much sense to me now. I just have one confusion now, I am passing an interpolated value like #m{{tabId}}, when I pass this as an input to my component, it throws an error saying expected an expression but instead got interpolation. Any work around to this?

Comment: You don't use interpolation syntax for inputs. You just put the value. So NOT like this: [myInputName]=
"{{someValue}}", but like this: [myInputName]="someValue". 

This assumes that "someValue" is a variable (or function return, so it could be "myValueFromAFunction ()") in your controller.

If all this is new to you, I highly recommend the Tour Of Heroes tutorial. Do it all, start from the beginning, step by step, slowly and attentively. Don't "yeah yeah yeah" any of the parts. It's really well thought out, going through it carefully is essential for the budding Angular-ist.

Comment: With all due respect @Tim, I understand property binding but I wanted to know how to bind a div id to component. Lets say I have a div that has an id=m{{tabId}} where m is constant and tabId is a variable, so I get different id's like m1, m2, m3 and so on. I think I haven't asked the question properly, sorry for ambiguities. It's my first time.

Comment: Hmm, just from the info in your comment, I would go "id={{ 'm' + tabId }}". 

Apologies if the Tour of Heroes thing seemed condescending, I absolutely didn't intend it to be. For the record I actually still refer to the advanced topics there, they did a bang up job on the whole thing.